# Is an isometry between compact boundaryless embedded surfaces necessarily a rigid motion of $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

A friend and I were discussing this and related questions as part of pre-exam revision, and we don't know how to answer this particular question (could not think of a proof or counterexample). Any help (ideally a solution) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is tagged [differential-geometry](/questions/tagged/differential-geometry), I'm assuming that the "isometry" you're talking about is not an isometry between *metric spaces*, with the global metrics each surface inherits from $\mathbb R^3$. (Every such isometry between arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ can be extended to a rigid motion).

Instead, I suppose that an isomorphy merely preserves the Riemannian metric of the surfaces -- or in other words, that it preserves arc lengths of curves *within* the surfaces. In that case there are counterexamples:

Take a compact boundaryless surface that contains the flat disc $\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\le 1, z=0\}$.

Replace this disc with
$$ \{(x,y,z)\mid z^2+y^2\le 1, z=s(x^2+y^2-1)^2\} $$
where $s$ is either $-1$ or $1$. The results of these two replacements are intrinsically-isometric surfaces, but the isometry does not extend to a rigid motion of $\mathbb R^3$.

---

Or if you don't require the surfaces to be connected, let each surface consist of two disjoint spherical shells and consider an isomorphism that rotates one but not the other ...